# Input type="number" selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to restrict the input in multiple forms and I'm trying to remove letters from the input on the keyup event. The problem is that It seems to work only on `type="text"` inputs, but I need it on `type="number"` inputs.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkfnxpvy/).

> NOTE: I need this working at Firefox and IE. On chrome this
>   functionality isn't neccesary.

```js
$(function(){
      
  $('input[type="number"], [type="text"]').keyup(function(e) {
        if(this.value!='-')
          while(isNaN(this.value))
            this.value = this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[\D]/i,'')
                                   .split('').reverse().join('');
    })
    .on("cut copy paste",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Remove the space? `input [type` -> `input[type`

Comment: which browser you are using to test? in chrome it works.

Comment: remove space. Use `input[type="number"], input[type="text"]`

Comment: I just edited, chrome doesn´t allow you to put text on number type inputs. I'm testing this at Firefox and IE11.

Comment: change your selector $('input[type="number"],input[type="text"]')

Comment: Why are you checking `isNaN`? It will alway be false...

Comment: Why are you checking for `'-'`? Why the split reverse join?  Why does your regex think that numbers need to be case-insensitive?  Why is your `\D` wrapped in `[]`? Why is there an `e` argument that's never used?

Comment: @BuhBuh IDK, that function isn´t mine, I only copied and pasted because seemed to work well at my tests

Comment: If you don't understand why something works, you really shouldn't just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, thanks for all the help, I think I finally solved here.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ixtrunai/tkfnxpvy/7/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '');">
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '')">
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have a space between the element selector and the attribute selector.

```
input [type="number"]
```

Should be:

```
input[type="number"]
```

The `[type="text"]` happens to work because it matches **all** elements with a type attribute that is set as `text`. It really should also be:

```
input[type="text"]
```

And the whole selector:

```
'input[type="number"],input[type="text"]'
```

---

There are also issues with the function - the two `split('').reverse().join('')`? Not needed.

A better approach for this function would be:

```
$('input[type="number"], input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/i, '');
})
```

Comment: I tried that, still not working on the type number input :(

Comment: @IXTRUnai it's because that even with this fix the function logic doesn't work.

Comment: @IXTRUnai - the logic you had for the function wasn't great - I've added a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Remove Space in between element(input) and attribute([type="text"])

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text'],input[type='number']").keydown(function(){
        $("input[type='text']").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
    $("input[type='text'],input[type='number']").keyup(function(){
        $("input[type='number']").css("background-color", "pink");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work with type="number", I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

The bug was happening because the way IE11 populates the `value` attribute is strange for type="number".
When I type `'1a'` then then `this.value` is `'1a'`, so your code executes correctly.
When I type `'a1'` then then `this.value` is `''`, so `isNaN('')` becomes false and your code doesn't execute.

I don't why IE11 is so strange.

I would recommend not using the `isNaN` and generally improving your coding standards.  There were many minor issues already noted in comments.

Here is an example which works in IE11.  (This still has some issues testing in Chrome, but you already stated you are not interest in Chrome)

```js
$(function(){
    $('[type="number"], [type="text"]').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    })
    .on("cut copy paste",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already posted an answer that also works. But, thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following link,

https://jsfiddle.net/tkfnxpvy/4/

use

```
$('input[type="number"],input[type="text"]'.keyup(function(e){
});
```